# SELECT query is pulling data, source table appears in MSysObjects, Hidden/System are both enabled, but table isn't listed in object browser

Tags: ms-access, hidden

I am completely perplexed.

A colleague's got a database issue. I noticed that the (internal) software that created the local database file with the problem, uses programmatic access to MS JET, which meant an easy first step was to see if MS Access (2010) was happy with the database - and then fix, export/import or repair, as a first step.

I copied the stand-alone local Jet data file to a non-networked virtual machine (so no chance of external data), and MS Access opened the db file easily, but I can't make sense of what I'm seeing.

MS Access is configured on that system to show all hidden and system objects, confirmed since the Access system tables in the file are all visible and can be opened. These are my observations:

1. The object browser lists the usual MS system tables, and a bunch of SELECT queries (which look correct) of the form SELECT (FIELD LIST) FROM (OTHERTABLENAME) WHERE (FIELDNAME=VALUE), nothing more.
2. The select queries show the usual grid with valid data records when opened, and the data looks correct as well.
3. No data tables with the given names are showing in the object browser interface.
4. The given names *are* listed as objects of the database, in the system table MSysObjects.

So.....  the underlying data tables ARE named in MSysObjects, and seem to be true data tables... but they are NOT being listed in the object browser and I can't figure how to open their datasheets (although MS Access' system tables are, and "Show hidden/system" are both enabled)... and the tables surely do exist in the file since an apparent SELECT query is pulling their data from them, and the file is on a clean non-networked machine with no other sources reachable.

Any ideas? I want to check the underlying data but ... whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I examined your database, I discovered the reason you can't access the tables normally is because the authors of the internal application which created the db file implemented measures to prevent normal access.

I advise you to contact them and your managers to get authorization and assistance to view the data.

Also, please be cautious with this question.  A suspicious person might uncharitably interpret your question as a disguised request for hacking help.  Please note I am *not* accusing you of anything underhanded ... simply asking you to notice how your question might be perceived.  And, if that were to happen, I don't know what the consequences would be on Stack Overflow, but I can't imagine it would be good.  So please be careful.

Comment: That's what I was missing. I didn't know where to find an answer. Usually if there's a security issue, there is a hint ("the database is protected") but Access's dialogs didn't give any clues. What I'm interested in, is not "how does one get round it" (which wasn't the point at all, thanks for not assuming!), but "my colleague's problem is due to some kind of database issue, but I can't find the problematic table to check for DB errors with a DB program". Your comment answers that. One question: to avoid my confusion in future, how does one check if there's a security restriction of the kind?

Comment: (Background for the record:- The program's an old one and the company's developer has long left, my colleague wanted to get a report from it that wasn't built in and knows I've done Access/VBA in the past. He asked me and my offhand answer was it sounds straightforward (use Access's own report generator). When I took a quick look, though, I couldn't figure why the data tables for those reports weren't listed. Now we know :) I've also deleted the uploaded sample DB based on your comment as well)

Comment: That db doesn't rely on standard Access security methods.  It uses custom methods I've not seen before.  So, when Access opens the db, it can't warn you the db is secured because it doesn't know.  The only way to know it's secured is to poke around, as you did, trying to get to the data you know it contains.

Comment: Regarding the departed developer, I think it may be an issue for your management to resolve.  They may need to replace the unsupported application.  That could also be an opportunity for you colleague to request the report he needs, or that the db design be revised to support ad-hoc user reports and queries.

Comment: That's very helpful and clear. Perfect answer, thanks. I'm guessing that in brief, Access as an MS Office program only uses a subset of Jet capabilities, so that a Jet DB can be configured programmatically via API and VB in ways Access doesn't use or "look for". As for my colleague - the business has 4 people, so they'll need other solutions. He was asking me as a colleague who might find him a shortcut. The simple answer is "can't easily be done, sorry". It's still an improvement on "I don't understand what I'm seeing" :)

Comment: I think that approach was devised by someone with advanced understanding of Access db design and operation who found a way to leverage Access' response to unusual object names to make it do something unexpected.  From a brief inspection, it looks clever.  If I had enough time and curiosity I would try to figure out the details.  But it's just not worth the effort because I have no use for it.